# How to retain character strings using positional indexing?

Tags: r, split

What I need to do is very similar to what the function below does

```
x = c("abcde", "ghij", "klmnopq")
tstrsplit(x, "", fixed=TRUE, keep=c(1,3,5), names=c('first','second','third'))
```

However, I would like to be able to return strings using ranges of values. For example, I would like to specify that in `first` I want to have the first two letters for each element.

Thus instead of having:

```
$first
[1] "a" "g" "k"

$second
[1] "c" "i" "m"

$third
[1] "e" NA  "o"
```

The output should look like

```
$first
[1] "ab" "gh" "kl"

$second
[1] "c" "i" "m"

$third
[1] "e" NA  "o"
```

Background:
I have a large .txt file of records and a lookup table that tells from which position to which position each attribute goes, and the expected max width from which position. The txt file looks like:

```
James         Brown M       01-01-1970
```

And then in a separate file I have a lookup table that says:

```
Field   Start     width
Name    1         7
FamilyN 9         7
Gender  11        1
```

Incidentally, I would appreciate any feedback on the best way to import this type of large .txt file. I feel like read.table is inappropriate since it tries to reduce to a dataframe format which is not what these files really are.

Comment: Seems like it would be easiest to change your splitting strategy. Maybe use `substr()` rather than `strsplit()`. Could you be more precise on exactly what the requirements are? How exactly do you plan to track how many characters you need and from what positions? Are you trying to parse some sort of fixed-width data?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for taking a look I added some background to my question hope it's more clear now

Comment: You're desribing fixed-width files. The easiest way to read them is probably with the [readr::read_fwf function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.0.0/topics/read_fwf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
x = c("abcde", "ghij", "klmnopq")

library(tidyverse)

list(c(1,3,5), c(2,1,1)) %>% 
  pmap(~ substr(x, .x, .x + .y - 1) %>% replace(., .=="", NA))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "ab" "gh" "kl"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "c" "i" "m"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "e" NA  "o"
> ```

I've hardcoded the positions. Per @MrFlick's comment, if you have a large number of strings, you'll need some strategy for deciding on the character positions so that you can automate it, rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: This is exactly what I have in fact. Could you briefly comment on the way to import .txt files as the one I mentioned in OP?